# One switch condition doesn't work while another does

Tags: javascript

I am working on a sort of fruitfly on screen, but programmed. First I wrote down very large codes, but I discovered that something was wrong. The fruitfly was only moving to the left but not to the right.

Code "To the right at 90 degrees":

```
case 90:
    fly.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(left) + sw).toString();
break;
```

Code "To the left at 270 degrees":

```
case 270:
    fly.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(left) - sw).toString();
break;
```

90 degrees is **not** working and 270 **is** working, but why is 90 not working? I only see that "+" is different than "-", whole code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<img id='fly' onclick='hi();' src='http://screen-bug.googlecode.com/git/fruitfly-moving.gif'>";
var fly = document.getElementById("fly");
var rotation = 0;
var ramargintop = Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height);
var ramarginleft = Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width);
fly.style.marginTop = ramargintop;
fly.style.marginLeft = ramarginleft;

var interval = setInterval(movefly, 50);
function movefly(){
//    rotation += Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) - 9.46);
    if(rotation < 0){
        rotation += 360;
    }else if(rotation > 360){
        rotation -= 360;
    }
    fly.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
    moveflyforward();
 }

function moveflyforward(){
    var topa = fly.style.marginTop;
    var left = fly.style.marginLeft;
    var sw = 0.2;
    switch(rotation){
        case 0:
            fly.style.marginTop = (parseInt(topa) - sw).toString();
        break;
        case 90:
            fly.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(left) + sw).toString();
        break;
        case 180:
            fly.style.marginTop = (parseInt(topa) + sw).toString();
        break;
        case 270:
            fly.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(left) - sw).toString();
        break;
        case 360:
            fly.style.marginTop = (parseInt(topa) - sw).toString();
        break;
        default:
            document.body.innerHTML = "<font color='red' size='30'>Error on fly, please contact Ebbe.z@live.nl about this. CODE: MoveForwardSwitch</font>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use a more descriptive question title. This is just not at all representative of any question at all.

Comment: Can you please post your entire code? This is not enough to be debuggable

Comment: Code is required to be *here*, not on other websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the use of `parseInt`

let's assume `left` is 10 (`sw` is 0.2)

when you add 0.2 to 10 the result is `10.2` on the next run `left` again will be 10(and nothing happens), because `parseInt` returns an integer.

When you subtract 0.2 from 10 the result will be `9.8`, on the next run `left` will be 9(also not the desired result).

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`(when you want to work with floats) or set `sw` to an integer, e.g. `1`